# How to use nspredicate in coredata

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

How to use nspredicate in coredata and what is cd while using these statements? Where can I get the best tutorials on core data predicate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see [cd] as part of a predicate, that means case-insensitive and diacritic-insensitive searching.

Check out Apple's Predicate Programming Guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

Hope this helps!